# Is it possible to generate a page based on flat file structure?

Tags: document-library, html

To preface, this question is coming from a complete beginner.

My situation is as follows:

After discovering that I can upload htm/html files to SharePoint Foundation and run them directly, I created a nice index for a library of documents and mini html sites that I'm making.

The index works well, but I have to hand code all of the links, which is tedious.

I would like to be able to write a short script that generates html output based on the folder structure of my document library. Basically a dynamic index that grows as I dump files into the library, with a specific structure.

This sort of thing would be really easy to do with PHP, but trying to figure out if it's even possible to do in SP is driving me nuts.

Is this sort of thing even possible?

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to add a web part page to the library, and then include a table of contents web part or a list view for the pages in that library.  Both of these can be done as configuration, and not require code.

Alternatively, just about anything can be done with code.  If you want them to be html pages, and not SharePoint pages, then you would look at using javacript to communicate with SharePoint through the web services to get the data.